# iPad mini Wi-Fi - can I use in UK and Australia?

Tags: ipad

I want to buy an iPad mini Wi-Fi for my sister whilst she is in UK travelling. She will then go back to Australia. Will it work there if she has downloaded apps in UK? Can she change her account to Australian store once home months later? It is only the Wi-Fi version I am looking at and not the the latest retina display one.

Comment: "only the Wi-Fi version... not the latest retina display" All iPads have wifi.

Answer (score 1):

You can continue using the previous account and country, for a change of country check this and contact Apple for further support:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201389